# Возможно ли задать initialValue метода reduce в стрелочных функциях?

Tags: javascript

нужно получить сумму всех свойств обьектов `amount` находящийся в массиве `orders`.

Я сделал это с помощью  анонимный функции но никак не смог релизовать с помощью стрелочных функций.

```js
const orders = [
  {amount:250},
  {amount:80},
  {amount:3},
  {amount:40}
];


let result = orders.reduce(function(current,order){
  return current + order.amount;
}, 0)
alert(result);
```

> ВОПРОС:Как задать `initialValue` в стрелочных функциях?

Мои попытки

```
let attempt = orders.reduce((index,current) => {index + current.amount}, 0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`initialValue` - это обычный параметр.

Здесь больше важна особенность того, как разбирается стрелочная функция.

при указании `(index,current) => index + current.amount` данная функция эквивалентна следующей

```
function (index,current)  { return index + current.amount}
```

В то же время при явном указании блока: `(index,current) => {index + current.amount}`

```
function (index,current)  { index + current.amount }
```

Отсюда видно, что функция ничего не возвращает.

Для решения нужно либо добавить `return`: `(index,current) => { return index + current.amount}`

Либо обернуть тело функции в круглые скобки, что позволит парсеру отделить тело функции от следующего параметра:

```
(index,current) => (index + current.amount)
```

примеры:

```js
const orders = [{
    amount: 250
  },
  {
    amount: 80
  },
  {
    amount: 3
  },
  {
    amount: 40
  }
];


let result = orders.reduce(function(current, order) {
  return current + order.amount;
}, 0)
console.log(result);

result = orders.reduce((current, order) => {
  return current + order.amount;
}, 0)
console.log(result);

result = orders.reduce((current, order) => (current + order.amount), 0)
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Если вы в стрелочной функции используете блок `{...}` то вы должны вернуть из него значение оператором `return`. Если же в стрелочной функции ровно один оператор и он же является результатом функции, то ни блока `{...}`, ни оператора `return` не нужно

```js
const orders = [
  {amount:250},
  {amount:80},
  {amount:3},
  {amount:40}
];

let result = orders.reduce((current, order) => current + order.amount, 0);
console.log(result);

result = orders.reduce((current, order) => {
  return current + order.amount;
}, 0);
console.log(result);
```